# Common undefined index error in PHP

Tags: php, xampp

When I am using my code in `wamp` (old php 3.2 may be) there is no warning or note but when I run the same code it is giving me a warning or a note:

> Notice: Undefined index: emailseaech in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\employee\RecruitingProcess\manageuser\pages\defaultresume.php
>   on line 6

for this

```
$emailseaech = $_GET["emailseaech"];
```

I am using ajax http to read the date passing value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$emailseaech = '';
if(!empty($_GET["emailseaech"]))
    $emailseaech=$_GET["emailseaech"];
```

Comment: it not working i tried that